# How to apply regexp for it?

Tags: json, regex, notepad++

I have big file with strings per line:

```
A1|-375,9|16,2|24,55|4,74|-6,28
B1|-151,9|9,5|11,67|1,08|-1,56
C1|-916,54|50|62,4|12,6|-12,46
D1|-143,84|6,4|10,18|1,74|-1,48
....
```

And with Search & Replace and Regexp I want to transform these strings to json objects like that:

```
{
    "name": 'A1',
    "h": -365.9,
    "s": 16.2,
    "a": 24.55,
    "b": 4.74,
    "c": -6.28
},
{
    "name": 'B1',
    "h": -151.9,
    "s": 9.5,
    "a": 11.67,
    "b": 1.08,
    "c": -1.56
}
...
```

Is possible to do it with regexp and Notepad++/Visual Code? Or maybe Can you propose better way to do it?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: ^^ + What language are you using to do this? Please include the right tags for more accurate feedback

Comment: @JvdV I want to do it with Visual Code (for example) or Notepad++  manually. I don't need any language. Just edit file manually.

Comment: Yes, possible. Better - use some full-fledged language, like Python, and do it in few simple steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find all commas and change on dots
2. Need to find by pattern

Find

`^([^|\n]+)\|([-.\d]+)\|([-.\d]+)\|([-.\d]+)\|([-.\d]+)\|([-.\d]+)`

Replace

`{"name":"$1", "h":$2, "s":$3, "a":$4, "b":$5, "c":$6},`

3. Done!